# Prime Factorization

Tags: number-theory, induction

Let $n\ge0$. What is the power of $2$ in the prime factorization of $(2^n)!\,$? Prove that the value is correct.

So far I've conjectured the value to be $2^n - 1$. This is true for $n=0,1,2,3,4$. Then I decided to use induction to prove the statement.

Base case: $(2\cdot0)!=1\cdot2^0=2^0-1$

IH: Assume for some $(2^n)!$, the power of $2$ in the prime factorization is $2^n-1$.

IC: Then it must be true for $(2^{n+1})!=(2\cdot2^n)!$

Am I using the wrong method?

Can anyone provide a proof?

Comment: Your conjectured formula is incorrect. For $n=3$ your formula gives the value $7$. In fact $6! = 720 = 16*45$. Therefore the correct result is $4$.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant 2^n.

Comment: I have a feeling the direct proof is the same as the inductive proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the exponent of a prime $p$ in the decomposition of $m!$
is $v_m(p)=\lfloor\frac{m}{p}\rfloor +\lfloor\frac{m}{p^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{m}{p^3}\rfloor+\cdots$

For the case $m=2^n$ and $p=2$ we have  $$v_{2^n}(2)=\lfloor\frac{2^n}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{2^n}{2^2}\rfloor+\cdots=2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\cdots +1=2^n-1$$
Your conjecture is correct.

Comment: Would you be able to prove the statement then? I'm unable to complete the proof as-is

Comment: prove which statement?the last step with summation or the situation with the exponent?http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml

Comment: The situation with the exponent (2^(n+1)  -  1)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Just count the 2s.

$(2^5)!=32!=32\times31\times\cdots\times2\times1$

Half of these are divisible by 2.

One fourth are divisible by 4 (so have one more factor of 2 than those divisible only by 4).

One eighth are divisible by 8 (so have one more factor of 2 than those divisible only by 2 and 4).